# How to install flickity carousel with vuejs and nuxtjs

Tags: npm, vue.js

I'm a new vuejs developer. I have study vueje for a while and now I decided to develop a project using vuejs.

So I learn about nuxtjs which is server side rendering. everything goes well. I can use bootstrap4 with my project.

Now I would like to use flickity carousel https://flickity.metafizzy.co on my project and I found that there is a vuejs package on https://github.com/drewjbartlett/vue-flickity

I follow the instruction how to install this component to my project by

```
npm install vue-flickity --save
```

and put on some code

```
<script>
  import Logo from '~/components/Logo.vue'
  import Searchbar from '~/components/Searchbar.vue'
  import axios from 'axios'
  import Flickity from 'vue-flickity';

  export default {
    data () {
      return {
        has_location: false,
        flickityOptions: {
          initialIndex: 3,
          prevNextButtons: false,
          pageDots: false,
          wrapAround: true
        }
      }
    },
    components: {
      Logo,
      Searchbar,
      Flickity
    }
  }
</script>
```

but it show **window is not defined**

[image]

I have try this with another component like google map, it's show the same error.

Please tell me what wrong did I do and how to install new component to the project.

Thank you.

Comment: This may help https://github.com/nuxt/nuxt.js/issues/1536#issuecomment-326266242 The main issue is it appears to be trying to access client side specifics within node (window object).

Comment: Thank you for reply. I follow this instruction but it show [Vue warn]: The client-side rendered virtual DOM tree is not matching server-rendered content....

Comment: Unfortunately, that's all I have for the moment. It appears someone else took the info from the link in my comment above and created an answer out of it. I'd say check with them as they appear to have it working; I don't have time at the moment to help investigate any further. Good luck!

Answer (score 7):

Nuxt.js use [SSR](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/ssr.html) to render your website server side, therefore `window` object is not accessible on node.js environment.

What you need to do is use the [**built-in** `no-ssr` component](https://github.com/nuxt/nuxt.js/tree/dev/examples/no-ssr) to prevent Nuxt.js to render it on the server side.

You can simply do this:

```html
<no-ssr>
  <Flickity :options="...">
    <!-- slides -->
  </Flickity>
</no-ssr>
```

> **UPDATE:** If you still get an error at this point, then load Flickity in
> a custom Plugin that you will load with `ssr` disabled

Create a file named `plugins/VueFlickity.js`

```js
import Vue from 'vue'
import Flickity from 'vue-flickity'

Vue.component('Flickity', Flickity)
```

Then in your `nuxt.config.js` your add:

```js
module.exports = {
  // ...
  plugins: [
    { src: '~/plugins/VueFlickity.js', ssr: false }
  ]
}
```

Don't forget to remove the Flickity local component registration:

```js
components: {
  Logo,
  Searchbar
  // Flickity <-- remove this line
}
```

This was tested and is now fully working.

Comment: It's important to remember to include plugins in clientSide render. You can also rename plugin file name to -> { src: '~/plugins/VueFlickity.client.js'} without defining the {...ssr:false} that's becuase Nuxt treat the name part of '...client..' as {ssr:true} :)

Answer (score 1):

I fixed it with:

```
let Flickity = {};
if (process.browser) {
    Flickity = require('flickity.js');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

@rayfranco pointed a great way.:) The thing is that by doing this in that way You're importing this plugin globally, but not as local component which is better for performance.
So You can do it also like this:

```js
let Flickity;

if (process.client) {
     Flickity = require('vue-flickity')
}

      
export default {
    components: {
       Flickity
    } 
}
```

and use this component this way:

Important: `<no-ssr>......</no-ssr>` is deprecated in Nuxt > 2.9, so use

```js
<client-only>
  <Flickity :options="...">
    <div class="carousel-cell">1</div>
    <div class="carousel-cell">2</div>
    <div class="carousel-cell">3</div>
  </Flickity>
</client-only>
```

you can also look into brief example by Josh Deltener
https://deltener.com/blog/common-problems-with-the-nuxt-client-only-component/